# Issue with creating an ubuntu service unit file for a program with a GUI

Tags: systemd, x11, systemd-unit

I am trying to write a unit service file for a program that has a GUI.

I have an ubuntu server from [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) and I connect to it with TightVNC to display:2.

The GUI requires a username and password to log in to my account online. While this program is open, it allows connecting to their server through port 4002 and request data online using a python script.

The program can be authenticated with a given username and password in the terminal. The following will open the program, automatically login to my account, and displays the program GUI.

```
$ /home/user1/ibg/ibg username=*** password=***
```

The unit file that I wrote is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=my service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/user1/ibg/ibg username=*** password=***
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service is active and running but I get the following message which I think prevents the service to be truly functional. I can tell this from the fact that my python script is not working. If instead, I open the program GUI, and log in to my account, the python program works with no issue.

```
No X11 display variable was set, but this program performed an operation that requires it.
at java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen(SplashScreen.java:117)
```

Could someone kindly help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `DISPLAY` variable to `:2` for your service's `ExecStart` environment?

See [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service):

You have an option to use either the `Environment=` flag directly in the `[Service]` section of your unit file, or you can use the `.conf` file approach described in the top voted answer in that question.

Comment: Yes, I tried both `0` and `2` by adding `Environment=Display:0` but it did not help. Still complains about `No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.`.

Comment: Environment variable names are case-sensitive. Try it with `Environment="DISPLAY=:2"`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.